# Silently authentication from webview

Tags: android

Here's what I want to have figured out : I'm using a webview to access a feature of a site that requires authentication. Therefore whenever that particular link is loaded the  login page is displayed . Is is possible to somehow authenticate silently so that the particular feature is displayed directly ?  Perhaps by using the "webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword" (which does not seem to work for me, or I don't do it right) or by making some POST or GET before I load the page , or other possibility ?

On logging in the server is simply supposed to send me a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

That method only works for HTTP Basic Auth, not for form-based login.

Your best bet would be to use the onLoadResource method of the [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to detect that the page is about to load, then override the content of the WebView using [loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a chunk of HTML/js that posts to the login form with the proper parameters, then detect the successful cookie return and forward on to the original url.

Depending on the site it may be messy: you may have to set the proper referer headers or CSRF tokens and other things of that nature.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Doesn't give me much hope though. I will keep looking ,perhaps there is some other approach.

Comment: Yeah, form-based authentication is kinda messy: the other alternative would be to write some java code (using HTTP client) to log in to the server, extract the cookies and then put the cookie into the webview's cookie manager (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html). That would probably work better.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked: if the cookie usage isn't too complex that does work.

Answer (score 0):

See, you could do the task this way, I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(
    WebView view,
    HttpAuthHandler handler,
    String host,
    String realm) {

    String currentUrl = yourWebView.getUrl();
    if(currentUrl.equals("www.yourwebsite.com")){
        handler.proceed("username","password"); 
    }

 }
```